# Rails seed not populating data for one of the models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails and trying to pass on some data in seeds.rb but doesn't show up when I do `rails c`. I am trying to add reviews for an airline but the count shows up as 0 instead of 2. So it doesn't seem to be adding the reviews for the first airline somehow.

seeds.rb

```
airlines = Airline.create([{ name: "Air New Zealand", image_url: "url.com" },
                           { name: "Jetstar", image_url: "https://www.jetstar.com/_/media/images/global/logos/jetstar-logo-black_svg.svg?la=en-NZ&hash=E2F625C27A6B66D3D129B3FB327F700503B14D7E" }])

reviews = Review.create([
  { title: "Good service", description: "service was good", score: 4, airline: airlines.first },
  { title: "Poor service", description: "service was poor", score: 2, airline: airlines.first },
])
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_04_17_115814) do

  create_table "airlines", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "image_url"
    t.string "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "score"
    t.integer "airline_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["airline_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_airline_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "reviews", "airlines"
end
```

airline.rb

```
    class Airline < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
  before_create :create_slug, :calculate_score

  #create a slug like 'url.com/air-new-zealand' for an airline
  def create_slug
    self.slug = name.to_s.parameterize
  end

  def calculate_score
    reviews.average(:score).to_f.round(2) * 100
  end
end
```

review.rb

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :airline
end
```

Comment: Maybe is a silly question but, did you run `rails db:seed` before?

Comment: @JuanArtau Yea I did run. The data for the airline works but not the review.

Comment: what do the logs look like when you run `db:seed`? maybe replace `create` with `create!` so if any fails you will get the error?

Comment: You might be getting a validation error which is not handled anywhere. Try replacing `create` with `create!`.